# 'Convert to latest Swift Syntax' breaks the build even when there are no changes

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7.1

My project is in objective-c with just one tableviewcontroller in swift. I downloaded the Xcode-beta today which prompted me to 'Convert to latest Swift Syntax'. After I follow the steps it shows me that there are no changes. I do not see any changes in the proj file either but it has errors.  Please note that I do not see the errors when I choose not to covert to latest swift syntax - the app builds and runs fine in this case.

Any idea why it is breaking?

[image: Screenshot added]

Here are the errors -

- cannot parse the debug map for "app name" No such file or directory
- clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
- the other errors are that it is not able to find the swift file. The swift class was initiated in the objective-c class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Product -> Clean` helped in my case.

Comment: @sss, did the other suggestion (from Pavlo) help?

Answer (score 15):

Switch `ENABLE_BITCODE` to `NO` in `project build settings` helped me.

Comment: @ViruMax glad to help ;)

Comment: This might be of an issue for app store apps

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue similar to this, and I fixed it by changing the `build phases`/ `compile sources` in the project :

I had added in new sources that needed to be compiled earlier in the project, and after i deleted the files, when I tried to build the project it said it was missing the files that I deleted. After deleting a few of the build phases that appeared as though they were not the default build phases, it worked fine.
I found that there were a default of 4 compile sources.

Also, using `Ctrl+Shift+K` will clean your project, which helped me another time with an error like this.

Comment: What did you exacly changed ?

Comment: I had added in new sources that needed to be compiled earlier in the project, and after i deleted the files, when I tried to build the project it said it was missing the files that I deleted. After deleting a few of the build phases that appeared as though they were not the default build phases, it worked fine. I found that there were a default of 4 compile sources. Also, using Ctrl+Shift+K will clean your project, which helped me another time with an error like this.

Comment: Fine ! Now everyone has better hints to solve this case. I updated your answer with this relevant comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and none of the above answers helped. Apparently, my issue was I had an import using a .m file instead of a .h file.

The easy way to find and fix these would be `Find > Find in Project...` and searching for `#import.*m` and changing them to the appropriate .h file