# Error after converting to the latest Swift syntax

Tags: swift

I've just downloaded the [Incognito starter project](http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Incognito.oauthswift_start.zip) and after I opened it, I converted it to the latest Swift syntax as the option was there. After that I got an error of `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` which I tried to fix using the advices from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812428/convert-to-latest-swift-syntax-breaks-the-build-even-when-there-are-no-changes). It helped me to fix the error. Then there were two other errors like this:

```
value of optional type 'NSData?' not unwrapped, did you mean to use '!' or '?'
```

and this:

```
value of optional type 'CGContext?' not unwrapped, did you mean to use '!' or '?'
```

For this function:

```
  func snapshot() -> NSData {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    self.view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let fullScreenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(fullScreenshot, nil, nil, nil)
    return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(fullScreenshot, 0.5)
  }
```

After listening to the constructor and fixing it, it turned out to be:

```
  func snapshot() -> NSData {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    self.view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let fullScreenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(fullScreenshot, nil, nil, nil)
    return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(fullScreenshot, 0.5)!
  }
```

But now I get the same error as in the beginning:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Click the linker error in the issue navigator to get more details about it, and post them. The problems are probably unrelated.

Comment: You're right it has nothing related to this. It gives a warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Incognito-bkpdxbihpouieqfokxbfztfezxot/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods'

And: 'framework not found Pods'.

But I'm still a bit confused, what should I do with the pods?

Comment: A good guideline is to start fresh with google, and if that doesn't help, ask another question for this problem. If it's a cocoapods project, you should make sure to never use the project file. Only use the workspace file.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. :)